# Is it possible to convert Thrift code to Async

Tags: c++, node.js, thrift, flume

I currently have the following C++ code which posts to a Flume using Thrift, but I need to do the same in a non-blocking fashion with a callback for use within Node.js.

```
boost::shared_ptr<TTransport> socket(new TSocket(logger->host_.c_str(), logger->port_));
boost::shared_ptr<TTransport> transport(new TFramedTransport(socket));
boost::shared_ptr<TProtocol> protocol(new TCompactProtocol(transport));
map <string,string> headers;
try {
    ThriftSourceProtocolClient client(protocol);
    transport->open();
    ThriftFlumeEvent evt;

    //headers["host"] = std::string(hostname);

    evt.headers = headers;
    evt.body = message;

    client.append(evt);
    transport->close();
} catch( ... ) {
    cerr << "\tException raised!" << endl;
}
```

Specifically, Java API has AsyncClient, does that exist for C++, and is it documented anywhere.  Google has not helped me so far.

Comment: Support was added to Thrift this week by Randy Abernethy to enable use of the TCompactProtocol within JavaScript, so this became unnecessary.  I did make progress beyond this, I found that you need to compile the Thrift extensions in COB mode and then you get async stubs, but I was unable to determine how to create the correct C++ objects to use those stubs.  C++ is not my strongest language.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [libuv](https://github.com/joyent/libuv) for async work. NodeJS also uses this library for async operations

Comment: That would be great if I were doing standard socket io, but then I would also be able to write async code.  The issue is that call to append needs to be split so it doesn't block.  I don't see how libuv could do that.  I see how the thrift project could use it underneath to implement nonblocking versions.

Answer (score 0):

Not impossible, or so it seems. I'm working on the same at the moment but I haven't got it working just yet.

I found two helpful links that may be of some use to you:

[A C++ client implementation](http://software.rtcm-ntrip.org/browser/ntrip/trunk/GnssCenter/thrift/rtnet_sdo_example?rev=4941&order=name) that has some classed that help with the missing bits of this [Java implementation](http://joelpm.com/2009/04/03/thrift-bidirectional-async-rpc.html)

There are also some pretty cool boost.asio ideas on the apache jira for [THRIFT-1](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/THRIFT-1)

It looks like all the info is there but I'm still bit confused :)

Hth

Answer (score 0):

[fbthrift](https://github.com/facebook/fbthrift)'s [cpp2](https://github.com/facebook/fbthrift/blob/master/thrift/doc/Cpp2.md) supports it. `fbthrift` is a fork of Apache Thrift.